# Android Rest Service Engine

Tags: android

Is there any kind of rest engine service.

In general having REST web service and android app that will fetch from it and make some data processing and have it displayed is something that fits to common pattern.

It would be natural to have service that could be queried over content provider or similar and retrieve data. Service would have some kind of definitions of data that it will fetch.

Anyone knows of something like that?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no REST API in Android, you can implement your own as it support Apache HTTP Client and JavaSE HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 3):

I just attended a presentation about RoboSpice at DroidCon 2012 London. It seems it can handle any networking task for you. Also, REST is built-in supported.

Check it out here: https://github.com/octo-online/robospice

Answer (score 2):

No such general purpose REST service engine exists. You could use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to fetch certain remote resources and then check to see when it is received and then process it yourself but there is nothing that provides the pattern of generic data processing and display.

Answer (score 2):

[Novoda RESTProvider](https://github.com/novoda/RESTProvider) looks promising. I haven't tried it yet, but it seems to have some parts covered.

Answer (score 0):

There is one approach I've used in the past. The fantastic thing about these is that it is really flexible.
It is based in requests (Runnable or Callables) which are created, setted up and enqueued within an executor (so yes, you can control the number of concurrent threads and the way requests are executed, you can even prioritize them). 
One another great thing is that you can decide what to do with the responses. I'd strongly recommend to parse to do this in the background transparently to the UI or the user (ie.: Writing directly into database, SharedPreferences, etc).

The last great thing is that you are able to get the response back when the request is finished in case you need to make some updates or present some info to the user. This can be easily done by setting up a callback which goes along with the request. Another option would be using Google Guava ListenableFuture as a callback.

There's a more in-depth explanation about the whole system here:
http://joseluisugia.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/theres-life-after-asynctasks-in-android/

And a very basic working example here with source code attached:
http://joseluisugia.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/using-runnables-queues-and-executors-to-perform-tasks-in-background-threads-in-android/

Hope it helps.
Answer back to keep on the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest carefully the Spring Android Rest Client. Its a beautiful api with JSON/XML... des/serializers and Connection Template, very easy to use.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html for more information.